# How to take reciprocal of a float in python

Tags: python, math, pygame

I'm having some trouble in my pygame application that I'm making. There are buttons in the menu that change how fast my simulation runs (by changing `speed` in `clock.tick(speed*10)`). This, however, also slows down the rate that the menu buttons respond. If I ingame set `speed` anywhere lower than 0.5 the speed and play/pause buttons take up to five seconds to register a click. So I tried creating my own way to work around this:

```
speed = 1 # defined previously ingame

timeSlow = 0
timeSlowGoal = 0

while True: # game loop

    if speed < 1:

        timeSlowGoal = reciprocal(speed) # well here's my problem

    else:
        timeSlowGoal = -1

    if timeSlowGoal != -1:

        if timeSlow >= timeSlowGoal:
            timeSlow = 0
            # more code that actually does stuff

        else:
            timeSlow += 1
            # doesn't match, try again
```

In python, there are tricks like `int()`,`string()`, and `float()` to change a variable. Of course, `reciprocal()` doesn't work. Is there some sort of function like these that gets the reciprocal of a number, (which in this case is always a decimal) or do I need to just do some fancy math to get it?

(of course if all of this is unnecessary and you have a better solution to my first problem let me know)

---

**EDIT:** Okay, there is a very simple solution to this that I overlooked. 1/n is **always** the reciprocal of n. There's no need for a reciprocal() function because it's so simple. That's what I get for forgetting elementary school math.

Comment: By reciprocal, do you mean 1/n ?

Comment: @jatinderjit Yes, that's a reciprocal of n if n is a whole number. That's easy. What I need is a way to get 2 from 1/2, 4 from 1/4, etc.

Comment: No, 1/n is always the reciprocal (regardless of n being whole number or even irrational). 1/(1/2) is 2.

Comment: Use `timeSlowGoal = 1.0/speed` to get the reciprocal, since - as we all learned in basic math at school, 1/(1/x) = x. Concerning the freezing of the buttons, you do not provide enough information to be able to find a solution.

Comment: Well looks like I've forgotten about that. Thanks jatinderjit for reminding me.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest They're freezing, because every tick a function checks if the mouse is hovering over them or has clicked. If a tick only happens once a second, it takes at least two seconds to register my click. I just needed to have the game and menu (which appear on screen simultaneously) to run at different speeds. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Python 3, change

`timeSlowGoal = reciprocal(speed)`

to

`timeSlowGoal = 1 / speed`

Just make sure that you don't try to do that if speed is zero.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why you are having such a huge piece of code, because [Reciprocal of a number](http://www.mathsisfun.com/reciprocal.html) can be simply mentioned as: `1/n`

So, your `reciprocal` function can be simply written as:

```
def reciprocal(n):
    return 1.0 / n
```

Here, I am using `1.0/n` instead `1/n` as in python for the resultant of division to be fraction, either *numerator* or *denominator* should have fraction value.

Sample run:

```
>>> reciprocal(3)
0.3333333333333333
>>> reciprocal(0.3333333)
3.00000030000003   # Not '3' because of the loss in the precision of value entered
>>> reciprocal(reciprocal(3))
3.0   # Doing reciprocal twice returns "3"
```

Comment: I assume that the second answer doesn't return 3 because your input does not repeat 3 forever (or at least until python doesn't care). Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @NoRt9001: When you write fractions like `1/3`, `1/6` as decimal, there is always some lose of precision.  When you inverse them again, the difference in original value is due the lose of precision at previous step

Comment: I'd use that and incorporate the `round()` function too, in case accuracy may be a factor later on with the variable.

Comment: @maze88: On second thought, it is not good as you will be playing with the precision of actual value. Because the result is different because we provided less precised value. `reciprocal(reciprocal(3))` returns `"3.0"`